# scala　関数を受け取る　引数内でのmatch case

Tags: scala

scalaのライブラリなどの実装を眺めていると
たまに

```
(1 to 100).foldLeft(0)((i,j)=>i+j)
```

と書くところを

```
(1 to 100).foldLeft(0){case (i,j)=>i+j}
```

という風に書いてある事があります。
下のmatch式が何故　コンパイルエラーにならないのか。
また何故このように書くのかがさっぱり分かりません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SLS 8.5 Pattern Matching Anonymous Functions で定義されています。FunctionN か PartialFunction が期待されている箇所に書くことが出来ます。

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-anonymous-functions